# Wordpress - using same exact slug for different posts

Tags: wordpress, url, slug

I looking for a a way to use the exact same slug url for a number of posts.

The url structure for my site is:
domain.com/category/slug

If I have created a post with a slug called "martin-nicolausson" in category "february" i would like to be able to create the same slug for the next month without wordpress adding a unique identifier at the end.

For a live example of what I mean; 
http://www.5070.se/february/jacob-astrom-2

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: you can't do it.

Long version: Since you can change what category a page/post is in, WP requires that the slug be unique across all pages/posts. Think of a `category` as an *attribute* of the post, as opposed to defining a namespace in which posts exist. Because the true namespace is global and flat, the slugs must be unique.